# Why my Page Speed Insights does not have a number on the score?

Tags: pagespeed-insights

[page speed score - ?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gfa4S.png)

I insert the website and after the score appears just with a "?"

Answer (score 0):

Your site is slow to reach. See screenshot attached.

Running your site from California, it takes over 3.2 seconds for FCP - first contentful paint.

This is not good. This is why page speed is unable to take screen shots as it is taking too long. Hence it times out and displays "?" if any of its tests are failing due to timeout.

You want to speed up FCP. Load only important elements on your viewport. Lazy load images and use defer, async for scripts.

You can gain better insights with Lighthouse. Use Chrome browser, incognito mode, load up your site and use incognito mode. It tells you things you need to fix.

Good luck[image: Page Speed][image: LightHouse]